# Clearing the InfoLog on the batch server

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

We have integration setup that creates purchase orders on the batch server.  For example the batch job may run and pick up 5 invoices coming from an external source and attempt to post them.
If 4 are successful and 1 fails, we catch the error using the code below:

```
errEnumerator = SysInfologEnumerator::newData(infolog.cut());
while (errEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    msgStruct = new SysInfologMessageStruct(errEnumerator.currentMessage());
    errException = errEnumerator.currentException();
    messageBody += msgStruct.message() + "\n";
}
```

Which works great in catching the error and then we return it into a log.  The issue is the entire message will be shown. "Number of vouchers posted to the journal 1." 4 times and then the error message.

After each successful post we do clear the infolog by doing `infolog.clear();`.
If you debug this code in X++ it does clear it each time and the error will only show the actual error without the previous successful posts.  But the batch job running on the batch server for some reason does not clear the infolog after each successful post.  After CILs, restarting services etc. nothing seems to work.
Is there another way to clear the infolog on the batch server? thanks

Comment: When you say "clear the infolog" on the batch server...are you talking about when you click the "log" button for a batch job? I think that data is stored in `Batch.Info` in a container.

Comment: no , i mean just the infolog... just seems like its not clearing when i run the job on the batch server but when i run it in debug mode it clears... just weird

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to store only the error lines in `messageBody` and not the 'success' lines, you don't have to clear the Infolog. You only need to add the following check at the beginning of your `while` cycle:

```
if (errEnumerator.currentException() == Exception::Info ||
    errEnumerator.currentException() == Exception::Warning)
{
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not mess with the infolog!

This will hide information, warnings and errors that you will need for example for batch problem solving.

So please do not `clear()` or `cut()`.

Instead copy what you want:

```
numLine = infologLine();
try
{
    // Do something useful
}
catch (Exception::Error)
{
    doTheLog(infolog.copy(numLine + 1, infologLine()));
    throw error("That did not work!"); 
}
```

First store the current infolog number. On error process the *relevant* infologs.

If the infolog is long consider transferring the numbers rather than *call by value* the container:

```
doTheLog(numLine + 1, infologLine());
```

Then `infolog.copy`in the method.